# how to add style to a string returned from a function called from the html file

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following code :

```
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Element Parent:</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput 
            (input)="getHierarchyService.filterFlatHierarchy($event)"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"
                [displayWith]="displayLabel">
                <mat-option class="mat-option-height" (click)="GetHierarchyLevel()"
                    *ngFor="let option of getHierarchyService.filteredHierarchyFlatData"
                    [value]="option">
                        {{returnSemiStringPath(option.Path)}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

the function returnSemiStringPath  returns a shortened string from the input :

```
returnSemiStringPath(path: string) {
    let newPathArray = path.split('/')
    return `${newPathArray[0]}/${newPathArray[1]}.....
   ${newPathArray[newPathArray.length-1]}/${newPathArray[newPathArray.length-2]}`
}
```

I want to add a style to the first part and last part of the new string (add color).

I thought to just "create" html elements from my ts file and append them from this function, with the styling I want. but I have no idea how to achieve this in angular.

*I know this function as it is probably a bad practice, I will turn it into an angular pipe to be more efficient after it works.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you want to add color first and last part of the returned string.
User Angular HTML binding, like this..

```
                <mat-option class="mat-option-height" (click)="GetHierarchyLevel()"
                *ngFor="let option of getHierarchyService.filteredHierarchyFlatData"
                [value]="option">
                    <span [innerHTML]="returnSemiStringPath(option.Path)"></span>
            </mat-option>
```

The returnSemStringPath function would get modified like this

```
returnSemiStringPath(path: string) {
let newPathArray = path.split('/')
return `<span class='redcolor'>${newPathArray[0]}</span>/${newPathArray[1]}.....
   ${newPathArray[newPathArray.length-1]}/<span class='bluecolor'>${newPathArray[newPathArray.length-2]}</span>`}
```

And the component decorator would look like this..

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styles: ['.redcolor { color: red; }', '.bluecolor{color:blue;}'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code can help you:

.ts

```
returnSemiStringPath(path: string) {
    const newPathArray = path.split('/');

    return newPathArray;
}
```

.html

```
<div class="hero">
  <div *ngFor="let hero of returnSemiStringPath('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997450/how-to-add-style-to-a-string-returned-from-a-function-called-from-the-html-file')">
    <span>{{hero}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want you can change the div block in *ngFor to span and remove span where is hero.

.css

```
.hero div:first-child {
  color: red;
}
.hero div:last-child{
  color: red;
}
```